# Safe and efficient method to adapt static class for modification

Tags: java

I'm adapting a simulation written in Java. My limited background is all in C++.

The current implementation of the simulation relies on a class called `Parameters`. An instance of class `Simulation` references attributes of `Parameters`, which I don't think is ever instantiated. The `Parameters` class has a structure like

```
public class Parameters {
  public static int day = 0;
  public static final int endDay = 365;
  ....
  public static int getDate() {
    return day;
  }
}
```

In an instance of `Simulation`, there are references to, e.g., `Parameters.day`.

Currently, all the attributes of `Parameters` are hard-coded. I need to be able to change some of them with command-line arguments. For example, I'd like to be able to set a different `endDay` using a `Parameters::setEndDay(int customDay)` sort of function.

My first thought was to create an instance (`Parameters parameters = new Parameters()`) and completely rewrite the `Parameters` class so that all its attributes are private and only accessible through accessor functions. **I'm concerned that this approach is not very efficient.** Thus far, I have tried a hybrid approach in which I create an instance of the `Parameters` class, which I then pass to an instance of `Simulation` while still occasionally referencing `Parameters.day` (something I don't need to change).

One of the problems is that I don't have a good sense of class privileges in Java.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The "best practices" way to do it is, indeed, the "inefficient" approach you discuss.  You shouldn't make the class or any of its fields or methods static, but instead, you should just have one instance of the class that gets used everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make all of them non-final, then you can just set them directly from your command-line arguments before instantiating the `Simulation` class:

```
// read command-line arguments

Parameters.endDay = 123; // this will change all reference to Parameters.endDay
new Simulation(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

create static method `setEndDay(int customDay)` in `Parameters` class. And you can change value without accesing with class not object: `Parameter.setEndDay(10)`. Note that `endDay` variable should be non final.

Answer (score 1):

### Accessing static member variables vs instantiating an object

Essentially this is a choice between global data or local data. A class variable (keyword static) exist in one place for your entire application. E.g. you cannot have two parametrizations running simultaneously in the same application (although you can run two applications in parallell or sequentially). Using instantiated objects you can have several Parameter objects containing different values.

### Accessor methods vs accessible member variables

There are some controversy around this. Schoolbooks usually state that all data should be encapsulated using accessor methods to protect the objects internal state. It is however as you state slightly less efficient and there are cases where making member variables directly accessible is considered good practice.

### Java Access Modifiers

Java supports four different access modifiers for methods and member variables.

- **Private**. Only accessible from within the class itself.
- **Protected**. Can be accessed from the same *package* and a subclass existing in any *package*.
- **Default** (no keyword). Only accessible by classes from the same *package*.
- **Public**. Accessible from all classes.

Comment: Consider revise the explanation for the protected access modifier.

Comment: I did not know that protected members were accessible from within the same package, thanks for the tip.